# Audio in a chrome extension; sometimes works, sometimes results in blank DOMException

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension for myself that plays a sound based on reading stuff from the DOM.

Sometimes the sound plays properly, sometimes it fails with

```
uncaught (in promise) DOMException
```

With no further information.

As I understand it, this is the type of issue that happens when you attempt to insert autoplay audio into a webpage without defaulting to muted. If that is the case, why is my extension working sometimes but not other times?

I can confirm that the DOM is parsed correctly, and the error happens in the following call to `play`:

```
let my_audio = new Audio(chrome.runtime.getURL("media/beep.wav"));
my_audio.play();
```

The media file is properly registered in the manifest.json

```
"web_accessible_resources":[
    "media/beep.wav"
],
```

Are there other causes to the `uncaught (in promise) DOMException` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly because you did interact with the page, which would leverage the autoplay policies in Chrome (beware it may not be enough in other browsers even if you may not target other browsers now).

Comment: This makes sense. Now I'm wondering if there is any way I can manually set my preferences so the audio plays for me each time. Maybe I should create another question for this

Comment: Maybe `chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy`